# What does "vpn include windows logon domain" mean in VPN setting?

Tags: vpn

In Windows7 or earlier, in a `VPN connection's properties > options`, there's a **"vpn include windows logon domain"** which is default enabled, and it don't change my experience if I disable it.

What does that function do?

Disabling it can improve security/privacy?

Comment: Disabling it would decrease your security and privacy if you use a VPN to log into a Active Directory domain.

Comment: In what way though?